# RegEx to Exclude TWO specific numbers

Tags: regex

I am modifying an MVC app over which I have to control to re-architect (or I would).  There is a data source that is an XML document and the application uses RegEx's to filter the document.  One filter is for a specific node NOT EQUAL to a specific number (7) and the RegEx being used is:

```
[^7]
```

Now, I need to filter based on that same node NOT EQUAL to two numbers (7 and 30).  I've tried a few things, but none that have worked (I am NOT a RegEx expert, more like a novice).

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Not enough information. Need more specifics about the content of the data, samples of what should and should not match, as well as whatever you've tried that didn't work. (If you've *tried a few things*, you should be able to include at least a couple of them. If you can't do so, you haven't tried *Really, teacher, I did my homework. The dog ate it!*.)

Comment: This is an entry in the web.config file.  The code uses the RegEx entry to create a new Regex object (Regex regexDepartment = new Regex(stringFromWebConfig, RegexOptions.ignoreCase);)  then there is a Linq expression to select matching elements in the XML document (from e in employeeXMLDoc() where regexDepartment.IsMatch(e.Element("Department").Value.  This works with [^7] but not with [^7|30] or  [^(7|30)] - all guesses, as I said, I'm a novice...

Comment: In plain English, I'm trying to select employees from an XML Document that are in all Departments EXCEPT 7 and 30.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a negative lookahead to exclude `30`/`7`:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/aP7gK5/1)

```
\b(?!30\b|7\b)\d+\b
```

This will essentially match one or more digit character(s) except if they are preceded by `30\b` or `7\b`.

Comment: Why not simply writing the check like `if(!match("/\b(30|7)\b/", string)) ...`

Comment: @hek2mgl Yep, that would definitely be better.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `[^7]` you can use

```
(?!7|30)
```

Comment: Remember the delimiters, otherwise your risk not matching numbers like `777` or `130`

Comment: but it sounds like what he wants.. just 7 and 30.

Comment: Exactly: 7 must not be matched, but 777 must be matched. Your regex does not match 777.