# Use Regex to exclude numbers based on certain conditions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match and extract numbers if:

- They are not a *single* 2
- They are not a *single* 4
- They are not a 4-digit number

*Note: Placement of numbers in the string is completely random - the numbers can occur at the beginning, middle, or end and can be any length other than 4.

Here is a table with examples of strings and desired matches.

| Text | Desired Match(es) |
| --- | --- |
| HELLO123 | 123 |
| B4UGO |  |
| 1984 ANIMAL FARM 45 | 45 |
| GOT 2 GO |  |
| SOME OTHER 1000 |  |
| 22 AND 44 AND 1234567 | 22, 44, 1234567 |
| TEST567TRUE | 567 |

I found an SO article that begins to address the single 2 and single 4 issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439420/regex-to-exclude-two-specific-numbers). The regex I have thus far is `'\b(?!2\b|4\b|\d{4})\d+\b'`, but that requires the numbers to be standalone (surrounded by spaces) and also will not extract numbers that have 4 digits, but exceed it (e.g. 1234567). I'd appreciate some help if anyone has some ideas.

Comment: That correctly captures the 7-digit number now, but still does not capture the first and last examples because of the breaks. Removing the breaks then causes issues with the 4-digit numbers :/

Comment: this might help in that case `(?<!\d)([01356789]|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{5}\d*)(?!\d)`

Comment: The comment of @jspcal works.
I also want to share my answer: `(?<!\d)([01356789]|([\d]{2,3}|[\d]{5,}))(?!\d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *negative* [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` as boundaries:

```
(?<!\d)(?!([24]|\d{4})(?!\d))\d+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lYEPYZ/5)

Inside the first negative look*ahead* disallowed numbers get [alternated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Comment: I think you can remove the `?:` and the last `(?!\d)`. Final version: `(?<!\d)(?!([24]|\d{4})(?!\d))\d+`. Good approach, different from the rest.

Comment: Thanks for comments! @LucasVazquez good catche(s) thank you. Do you think there is any advantage about changing the *non-capture* group to a normal group? I don't see any but actually I'm just used to non-capture groups where capture groups are not needed. :)

Comment: @bobblebubble, thanks for the initial suggestion

Comment: @LucasVazquez, thanks for the edit - both work great

Comment: @AlisonLT Welcome! Yes in my [first suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/lYEPYZ/1) I had accidently `\b` boundaries in the lookbehinds. Correctly it would be [`\d+(?!\d)(?<!(?<!\d)\d{4})(?<!(?<!\d)[24])`](https://regex101.com/r/nSD3RS/1) and about twice as efficient but it's a longer pattern and I guess harder to read.